# JS can't set style property

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Ok let's look at this part of the code -

```js
$(tbody).find('tr').each((i, oldTbodyTr) => {
    newTr = document.createElement('tr');
    $(oldTbodyTr).find('td').each((i, oldTd) => {
        let newTd = document.createElement('td');
        newTd.innerHTML = oldTd.innerHTML;
        newTd.classList = oldTd.classList;
        newTd.style = oldTd.style; //Doesn't work
        newTr.appendChild(newTd);
    });
    newTableTbody.appendChild(newTr);
});
```

It creates a new table body by looping through all rows in `tbody` of an already existing table.
Everything is fine, except that the style of the old `td` doesn't transfer to the new `td` element.
I can't figure out why.

Comment: Why not simply define your styles in CSS and assign a class? How many style properties have you defined? You’d need to transfer them one by one.

Comment: It's not about my styles. Actually I'm writing a function to grab a simple table and deliver a full-featured and pretty one. Something like DataTables. It must be universally working.

Comment: Are there any inline styles you want to copy?

Comment: Yeah I need all styles from older td to be copied to new td. Entire object. As Sebastian mentioned, style is read-only property. So I wonder how to transfer all of it.

Comment: If you also want to copy inline styles, use `newTd.style.cssText = oldTd.style.cssText` instead.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Perfectly worked :)) Can you post that as an answer so I can vote it as correct?

Comment: Just did :) Glad it helped

Comment: @OP, have you considered simply using `newTableTbody.append(tbody.cloneNode(true))` for your case?

Comment: @Kaiido newTd = oldTd simply does that. But I didn't want entire object to be copied. Only classes, styles and innerHTML.

Comment: @SoroushBgm `newTd = oldTd` doesn’t copy anything other than the reference of `oldTd` to the binding `let newTd`, i.e. you’re just reassigning your variable. It neither affects `newTd` nor `oldTd`. No properties are being copied.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I thought when we grab an element and store it in a variable, we are actually storing an object. We can also copy objects like this obj1 = obj2. The point you mentioned is tricky. I should read more about that.

Comment: See [Modifying a copy of a JavaScript object is causing the original object to change](/q/29050004/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy inline styles, you could try `newTd.style.cssText = oldTd.style.cssText` since `style` itself is immutable.

> See more about [`style.cssText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/cssText).

```js
const source = document.getElementById('source');
const target = document.getElementById('target');

target.style.cssText = source.style.cssText;
```

```html
<p id="source" style="color: red; background-color: blue; font-size: 20px;">Source</p>
<p id="target">Target</p>
```

Comment: [`HTMLElement.style`](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#the-elementcssinlinestyle-mixin) is [`PutForwards=cssText`](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#PutForwards), so doing `elem.style = foo` is exactly the same as doing `elem.style.cssText = foo`. If OP's code didn't work it's because `elem.style.toString()` will return `"[object CSSStyleDeclaration]"` (or `"[object CSS2Properties]"` in FF) and not the intended cssText. So they can very well just write `target.style = source.style.cssText;`